# Search for a single value in a multi_value column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which there is a column which stores id(s) of another table, there could be a single id or multiple ids separated by  a comma (,).

I want to search for the row(s) where the id is available, id can be available in any of the column whether it has a single id or multiple ids.

```
| id | s    |
+----+------+
|  1 | 2    |
|  2 | 1    |
|  3 | 2    |
|  4 | 2,3  |
|  5 | 1,3  |
|  6 | 1,2,5|
+----+------+
```

So if I use

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE other_table_id=2
```

It should return 4 rows as the id 2 is available in 4 different rows, but it only returns 3 rows where the id 2 is at the beginning.

Why is it not including the last row where id 2 is in the middle?
How can I resolve this?

Please help!

Comment: 'Why is it not including the last row where id 2 is in the middle?; - because only an equality on the full string would meet the equals condition...and a mysql quirk which will see 2 because it;s the first node of a string..

Comment: Any solution to archive the desired result?

Comment: Try FIND_IN_SET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) , but it will be very slow for larger data

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2,s)>0;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3e9a3ca9340d95a1af2e66db935e9411)

Or you could use `CONCAT`

```
select * 
from tablename 
where CONCAT(',', s, ',') like '%,2,%'
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e27ea613200355d8bd1cbea2e63df7eb)